# Can you find a counter example for this sketch of a solution to the halting problem?

Tags: turing-machines, halting-problem

if we define halting problem as follows

$
\begin{align*}
h(m,n) &= 
   \begin{cases}
      1 & \text{if program $m$ halts on input $n$} \\
      0 & \text{otherwise} \\
   \end{cases}
\end{align*}
$

and we have two sometimes correct solutions $f$ and $g$ for $h$ that are always correct if they agree but fails to agree if the input is a counter example

then we can compute $h$ as follows

$
\begin{align*}
h(m,n) &= 
   \begin{cases}
      f(m,n) & \text{if $f(m,n)=g(m,n)$} \\
      h(t(m),n) & \text{otherwise} \\
   \end{cases}
\end{align*}
$

```python
def h(m,n):
  if f(m,n)==g(m,n):
    print(f(m,n))
    while True:
      continue
  print(0)
  h(t(m),n)
```

where $t(m)>m$ has the same behavior as $m$

now the question is: can you find a counter example? if not can we find $f$ and $g$?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139779/discussion-on-question-by-raoof-can-we-solve-the-halting-problem-if-we-allow-tm).

Comment: @D.W. I'm claiming that the standard proof of non-computablity of halting problem has a flaw  (at least for me) , if we want to prove that $h$ is non-computable we have to show that $f$ or $g$ are non-computable. now I'm saying assuming that $f$ and $g$ are computable then $h$ solves the halting problem, now the question is can you prove that $f$ or $g$ is non-computable or find a counter example for my $h$ like the standard proof

Comment: @D.W. maybe it's get too confusing. let's for a moment forget that the halting problem is non-computable. there is a well defined problem called the halting problem that I find a solution for it ($h$) that has to missing peaces ($f$ and $g$), can you find the missing peaces or prove to me that my solution is not correct and those missing peaces won't solve it by giving a counter example?

Answer (score 1):

Please recheck definitions in Turing's paper.

1. Circular machines *never* halt, and they get *stuck*, hence the term "circular". In a sense, the algorithm being executed by the machine (machines and algorithm are same) is *not applicable*. Which is why, as Turing remarks, they either enter into a state from which there is no possible move, or they keep doing rough calculation but never print symbols 0,1 (which constitute the computed number).
2. Circle-free machines will
   successfully print any number of digits of decimal (i.e. can halt). Here halting is the point. A circle-free machine never gets stuck, and therefore, *can* halt. Turing proves that there cannot be a universal halt tester.

Comment: Turing didn't have halting problem. Circular machine can halts: "A machine will be circular if it reaches a configuration from which there is no possible move, or if it goes on moving," [1936 ON COMPUTABLE NUMBERS. 233] on the other hand a circle-free machine never halts: "If a computing machine never writes down more than a finite number of symbols of the first kind, it will be called circular. Otherwise it is said to be circle-free."

Comment: Turing was only interest in circle-free machine meaning those machines that never halt

Comment: "A machine will be circular if it reaches a configuration from which there is no possible move" - you enter a state from which there is no possible move i.e. you look into m-config table and you cannot find what to do next.

Comment: " on the other hand a circle-free machine never halts " - yes, here Turing is speaking of number with infinite decimal places.

Comment: "If a computing machine never writes down more than a finite number of symbols of the first kind, it will be called circular" - a circular machine can halts

Comment: Yes, and in the lines which follow, Turing gives exact definition of circular machines.